# AWS - Unable to access S3 bucket object from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am not sure if I am missing a step here or not.

I have an s3 bucket I need to be able to access from an AWS SDK PHP script I wrote running on my EC2. I created an IAM role to allow access.

**IAM Allow_S3_Access_to_EC2**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myinbox"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myinbox/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myinbox/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And my Trust Relationship for the IAM role is

**Trust Relationship**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I then attached that IAM role to my EC2 instance. From what I have read this is all I have to do, but I think I need to do more.

In my Bucket Policy I have the following to allow access from my SES to be able to create the email object.

**S3 Bucket Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSESPuts",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ses.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myinbox/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:Referer": "************"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::************:role/Allow_S3_Access_to_EC2"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myinbox",
                "arn:aws:s3:::myinbox/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My Bucket Policy has nothing in there for my EC2 or even my IAM role I have attached. Do I need to add something to my Bucket Policy as well? That is where I am confused.

What I am experiencing is when a new object is created and I try and access that object from my AWS SDK PHP I get a "403" Forbidden. If I make that object public in the S3 console I can then access it just fine. So even though I have set permissions for my EC2 to access my S3 unless I make the object public I can't access it.

I even tried using `wget` to the object on the actual server through the terminal and I still get the `403` unless I make the object public

When I run the IAM Policy Simulator on my role I get

[image]

Here is my PHP

**PHP Script**

```
require '../aws-ses/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucketName = 'myinbox';

try {
// Instantiate the client.
    $s3 = new S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => 'us-west-2',
        'credentials' => array('key'=>'*********************',
                    'secret'=>'*******************************************')
    ]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // We use a die, so if this fails. It stops here. Typically this is a REST call so this would
    // return a json object.
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
// Use the high-level iterators (returns ALL of your objects).
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => $bucketName));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, did you set up the trust relationship so that the EC2 service can assume that role?

Next, you don't associate IAM roles directly with EC2 instances; instead you need to use an Instance Profile. Did you set up an Instance Profile associated with that Role?

This document is a good start: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the trust thing. I attached the IAM role to the EC2 from checking the instance in the console > Actions > Instance Settings > Attach/Replace IAM role. Is that not the way to do it?

Comment: Looking at my IAM role I see under the Trust Relationship tab `The identity provider(s) ec2.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Yes: The "Trust Relationships" seem right. Do you see an "Instance Profile ARN" populated at the top of your Role Summary?

Comment: Yes, `arn:aws:iam::****************:instance-profile/Allow_S3_Access_to_EC2`

Comment: Perfect. Then yes, you do need a statement in your Bucket Policy to allow read access from your EC2 instance.

Comment: And to be clear, you should create a Bucket Policy that gives read access to your _role_. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/

Comment: I edited my question with the new bucket policy adding the IAM role and still no go

Comment: Even though I have "Block Public Access" The IAM role should still allow those objects inside the bucket?

Comment: Yes! Even though you have Block Public Access turned on, your bucket policy should allow access from your EC2 role.

Comment: I'm lost then, I have updated my question with all my updates JSON code for all my policies and everything seems to be correct yet I still get a `403`

Comment: You should have everything you need. It's a bit difficult at this point to debug from a distance. What I would do next is SSH into the EC2 and try the `aws s3 ls s3://myinbox` from the CLI (assuming you have the AWS CLI installed). You can also run `aws sts get-caller-identity` on the EC2 instance to confirm it is assuming the right role.

Comment: Just ran both those commands and they work?? I was able to see the objects. Is it my script then maybe? I added it to my question at the bottom

Comment: AH ... I've never used the PHP AWS SDK, but you don't want to pass in an access key/secret ... you want to get the credentials from the EC2 environment!

Comment: Most SDKs have a Provider "chain" concept. You can usually use the default provider chain when using the SDK from an EC2. Try the example at the top of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Credentials.CredentialProvider.html

Answer (score 0):

1)  I would make sure that you're ec2 is using the role to call the s3, use the command below to identify

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

2) I would revoke existing sessions to make sure the new session has refreshed the roles

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_revoke-sessions.html

3) use the  S3 access analyzer to define the access resolving

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/access-analyzer.html

Comment: I did first 2 and they are good and done, can you expand on the third?